# Blue Outline around View

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface

I have been experincing this error for around a day now and I can't figure out how to get rid of the blue lines that go around everything in the view. I have been getting an error on and off that says "Internal Error has occured, may cause editing problems." 
[image: You should be able to see the blue lines around the user interface, this only occurs in editing but not when it is on the device]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to Uncheck "show layout rectangles" and "show bounds rectangles"

[image]