# Xcode Storyboard Shows Blue Frames Around UI Elements. How do I turn this off?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

I'm honestly not sure what I did here. I've never seen this before. Xcode is now showing blue frames around every UI Element in my Storyboard. This goes for ALL View Controllers inside it. How can I undo this or fix this?

Please See Screenshot Below:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blue Outline around View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717103/blue-outline-around-view)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

They are the bounds rectangles for your UI elements - they help you see the size of the various elements where it may not be immediately obvious due to background colours etc.

You can turn them off by going to the Editor menu->Canvas->Show Bounds Rectangles

[image]

Comment: Wow - that was it! Thanks @Paulw11! I'm still not sure how it happened because I can tell you right now that I never went to the Editor > Canvas menu. I would have known how to fix it if I did! haha I was able to find other awesome features in that menu.

Comment: Yeah. This "solution" doesn't work on XCode 8 at all. XCode 8 seems to be the most buggy XCode ever released. SMH...

Comment: This solution didn't help on XCode 8 and above. Restart your system after closing all apps and open Xcode alone - this solved issue for me(using Xcode 8.2.1).

Comment: I never noticed this. Finally!

Comment: I have found that this option toggles itself on automatically sometimes, like when you're moving lots of elements around the screen and an operation times out (which seems to happen frequently with just ~20 elements selected). I had to turn it off and on and off again before the blue rectangles disappeared.

Comment: If the changes don't apply immediately you'll probably need to restart Xcode

Answer (score 39):

In Xcode 9, turn off Editor->Canvas->Show Bounds Rectangles. The rectangles still don't disappear. Turn it back on, and then turn it off again, and the problem should be resolved.

Comment: For me it helps, but then after switch to a code and back to the storyboard turn them on again automatically...

Comment: Agreed with @norlin. This works, but you have to do it every time you switch back to storyboard from code.